# I can only use vector space properties and a theorem to prove statements, how would I do so?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

I have a couple of statements that I can only solve using certain methods, we have a given vector space **S** and

I can only solve using the ten properties of proving a vector space, and the theorem that says:

"If **V** is a vector space, then 0$\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ and $-\vec{x} =(-1) \vec{x}$ for all $\vec{x}$ $\in$ **V**"

---

(1) The first statement is 
If $\vec{v}$ $\in$ **S** satisfies $\vec{v}$ = 2$\vec{v}$ then $\vec{v}$ = $\vec{0}$

(2) The second statement is if $\vec{x}$ $\in$ **S** and c is a real number, then the additive inverse of c$\vec{x}$ = (-c)$\vec{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{v} = 2\cdot\vec{v}$. Add $-\vec{v} = (-1)\cdot \vec{v}$ to both sides, and use that $\vec{v} + -\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ to get $\vec{0} = 2\cdot \vec{v} + (-1)\cdot\vec{v}$.

Now use distributivity on the right: $\vec{0} = (2 + (-1))\cdot\vec{v}$ which equals $1\cdot \vec{v} = \vec{v}$ by another axiom. Done.

Now for all scalars $c$ and all $\vec{v}$: $c\cdot \vec{v} + (-c)\vec{v} = (c + (-c))\cdot \vec{v}$ by distributivity again. As the scalars form a field, this equals $0\cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ by the property you are allowed to use.

Now we know that addive inverses are unique in an Abelian group: if we fix $x$ and both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are such that $x + x_1 = 0 = x + x_2$ then $x_1 = x_2$ (e.g. just add $-x$ to the left etc.).

We've shown that both $-(c \cdot \vec{v})$ and $(-c)\cdot \vec{v}$ do this for $x = c \cdot \vec{v}$, so these are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If $v=2v$ then $2v-v=v=0$

$cx+ (-c)x=(c+(-c))x=0x=0$ just use distributive law

Comment: Unfortunately I have conditions that I can only use certain properties to prove these statements, and that is why I couldn't solve the question.